# jQuery cycle2 plugin: hide controls if only 1 image

Tags: jquery, controls, slideshow, show-hide

I have created a wordpress website where i have integrated the cycle2 plugin into the gallery. When the user adds more than 1 image the controls show up and the slideshow transitions start. I want the controls to hide when there is only 1 image.I have a snippet of code that will aid the development of the process but tried adding css display:none into the function and nothing happens. If someone could guide me this would be great as i've tried different methods.

Plugin: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle2/

CSS:

```
.cycle-slideshow {
    height:400px;
    z-index:0;
}
.cycle-slideshow  img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:3;
}
.center {
    display:block;
}
.center a{
    z-index:4;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-48px;
}
.center a:hover {
    display:block;
}
.center a#prev, .center a#next{
    position:relative;
    width:4%;
    height:60px;
    width:60px;
    margin-top:-60px;
    font-size:40px;
    text-align:center;  
    color:#FFF;
}
.center a#next{
    float:right;
    background:url(images/next.png) center -2px no-repeat;
}
.center a#prev {
    float:left;
    background:url(images/prev.png) center -2px no-repeat;
}
```

HTML: The html for this is huge and integrated into php functions but it is along the lines of:

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" 
    data-cycle-fx=fadeout
    data-cycle-timeout=1000
    data-cycle-pause-on-hover="true">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/p1.jpg">
    ...
</div>
```

Snippet of jQuery (where i am confused):

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
            $('.cycle-slideshow').on( 'cycle-initialized', function( e, opts ) {
            if ( opts.slideCount > 1 ) {
                $(".center").css("display", "none");
            }
            });
        });
```

I also get no errors in my console.

Answer (score 1):

You say you want the controls to hide when there is only one image. But with:

```
if ( opts.slideCount > 1 ) {
    $(".center").css("display", "none");
}
```

you hide them when there is more then one image.